# ¿Cómo eliminar el apóstrofo de un archivo csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, script, unix

Traté de eliminar el apóstrofo (') de un archivo csv para enviarlo en elasticsearch en la medida en que él me envió este mensaje en mi último intento :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Data/on_2018_04_25_16_43_17$ ./importCSVFiles
{"error":{"root_cause":
            [{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],
          "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
          "reason":"failed to parse",
          "caused_by":{"type":"i_o_exception","reason":"Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): 
              has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@e18584; line: 1, column: 88]"}
         },"status":400
}
```

Las primeras líneas del archivo son:

```
{' AccreditionType': ' Accredited by the American Veterinary Medical Association (AVMA).', '[AccreditingBodyName': '[American Veterinary Medical Association (AVMA)', ' KiscourseID]': ' UBVETMD]', ' KisCourseTitle': ' BVetMed (Hons) Bachelor of Veterinary Medicine', ' HEP': ' (10007779) The Royal Veterinary College'}
{' AccreditionType': ' Accredited by the American Veterinary Medical Association (AVMA).', '[AccreditingBodyName': '[American Veterinary Medical Association (AVMA)', ' KiscourseID]': ' UBVETMI]', ' KisCourseTitle': ' BVetMed (Hons) Bachelor of Veterinary Medicine with Intercalated Year', ' HEP': ' (10007779) The Royal Veterinary College'}
...
```

Parace ser un diccionario.

Utilisé el siguiente codigo python para extraerlas :

```
import csv
with open('AccreditationByHepModified.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for i,row in enumerate(reader):
        print(row)
        if(i >= 9):
            break
```

Pero sobre LibreOffice Calc no parece que hay comillas:

[image: csv archivo pero hay comillas]

**Entonces, ¿cómo eliminar las citas del archivo para que Elasticsearch lo acceptan mientras que no aparecen sobre el GUI ?** Probé este script de Python sin éxito :

```
import csv
import string

input_file = open('AccreditationByHep.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('AccreditationByHepModified.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(output_file)
specials = "'"

for line in data:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line,specials,'')
    writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Intenté con "\'" tambien pero no funciona tampoco.

#### Queda ciertas cuendo intento eliminarlos con awk

Intenté con `awk` pero queda ciertas como aqui :

```
Nursing and Midwifery Council (NMC),Recognised by the Nursing and Midwifery Council (NMC) for the purpose of registration as a qualified nurse (child).,(10000824) Bournemouth University,BSc (Hons) Childrens and Young People's Nursing,BSCYNHF_B702
```

O aqui :

```
The Independent Game Developers Association (TIGA),"Accredited by TIGA (The Independent Game Developers' Association) as delivering skills relevant to the games industry. TIGA accreditation is applicable to courses meeting any of a wide range of games industry needs, such as programming, art, design and entrepreneurship.",(10000291) Anglia Ruskin University,BA (Hons) Computer Games Art,K00009
```

Comment: Puedes intentar reemplazarlo con \'

Comment: @alanfcm No funciona tampoco :(

Comment: "Las primeras líneas del archivo son..." y lo que muestras no es un csv, sino un JSON.

Comment: El archivo más que un csv parece ser un conjunto de representaciones de diccionarios Python o JSON  no del todo válidos (las comillas deberían ser dobles)... Prueba a remplazar las comillas simples por dobles. `str.replace("'", '"')` o mediante `json.dumps` previo parseo de la fila a diccionario

Comment: @FJSevilla Desafortunadamente cuando intento reemplazar las comillas simples por dobles con `str.replace(line, "'",'"')` me da, con el script de visualización que agregué encima :
`{' "KiscourseID"]': ' "UBVETMD"]', '["AccreditingBodyName"': '["American Veterinary Medical Association (AVMA)"', ' "HEP"': ' "(10007779) The Royal Veterinary College"', ' "KisCourseTitle"': ' "BVetMed (Hons) Bachelor of Veterinary Medicine"', ' "AccreditionType"': ' "Accredited by the American Veterinary Medical Association (AVMA)."'}`. Es quasi lo mismo cuando utiliso `str.replace(line, "\'",'\"')`

Comment: Coincido con @FJSevilla, creo que estas partiendo además de una serialización que tiene problemas. Como se entiende esta cadena por ejemplo: `'[AccreditingBodyName': '[American Veterinary Medical Association (AVMA)', ' KiscourseID]': ' UBVETMD]'`?

Comment: Pienso que hay un error esta `AccreditingBodyName : American Veterinary Medical Association`, `KiscourseID:  UBVETMD`

Comment: Pienso que hay un error esta `AccreditingBodyName : American Veterinary Medical Association`, `KiscourseID:  UBVETMD`

Answer (score 0):

Al no poder tener éxito con un script de python, cambié a `awk` y `sed` con éxito :

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub(/\047/, ""); print}' AccreditationByHep.csv > AccreditationByHepModified.csv
```

Y despues

```
sed -i 's/\x27//g' AccreditationByHepModified.csv
```

Sin ser aceptado por Elasticsearch :( Quedo con este error :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Data/on_2018_04_25_16_43_17$ ./importCSVFiles 
{"error":{"root_cause":
          [{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason":"failed to parse"}],
          "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
          "reason":"failed to parse",
          "caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception",
                       "reason":"Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n 
        at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@6a29f40e; line: 1, column: 88]"
                       }
          },
    "status":400
}
```